# How to create new columns in dataframe based on conditional matches on another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

### Situation

I have two dataframes `df1` that holds some information about cars:

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }
```

and `df2` that holds media types corresponding to the cars in `df1`:

```
images = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Toyota Corolla','Audi A4'],
        'MediaType': ['A','B','C','A','B','C']
        }
```

### Expected result

In result I wanna create an overview in `df1` that tells if there is a media type available for the car or not:

```
result = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
          'MediaTypeA' : [True,True,False,False],
          'MediaTypeB' : [True,True,False,False],
          'MediaTypeC' : [False,False,False,True]
        }
```

### How can I realize this?

I already could check if a `Brand` from `df1` exists in `df2`, what tells me there is or there is no media type available at all:

```
df1['check'] = df1['Brand'].isin(df2['Brand'])
```

but I am not sure how to glue it with the check for the special media types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) for indicators,  create unique index by `max` and add to first `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), last replace missing values:

```
df11 = pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('Brand')['MediaType'], dtype=bool).max(level=0)
df = df1.join(df11, on='Brand').fillna(False)
print (df)
            Brand  Price      A      B      C
0     Honda Civic  22000   True   True   True
1  Toyota Corolla  25000   True   True  False
2      Ford Focus  27000  False  False  False
3         Audi A4  35000  False  False   True
```

If possible some missing values in `df1` then need [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `fill_value=False`:

```
df22 = pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('Brand')['MediaType'], dtype=bool).max(level=0)
df = df1.join(df22.reindex(df1['Brand'].unique(), fill_value=False), on='Brand')
print (df)
            Brand  Price      A      B      C
0     Honda Civic  22000   True   True   True
1  Toyota Corolla  25000   True   True  False
2      Ford Focus  27000  False  False  False
3         Audi A4  35000  False  False   True
```

Comment: Is there also a way to use get_dummies() getting same result but with string values? `'MediaTypeA' : ['A_','B_','B_','V_'],...`

Comment: @HedgeHog - So difference is `_`? Not sure if understand

Comment: Difference is string or int instead of bool in the result - May it is better to create a new question? :)

Comment: @HedgeHog - If need integers `0,1` remove `, dtype=bool` from `pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('Brand')['MediaType'], dtype=bool`, if need `0,1` strings use `pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('Brand')['MediaType']).max(level=0).astype(str)`